# r: efficient way to merge data when there is common column and combine data when there is no common column

Tags: r, merge

I have two data frames with duplicate columns, `data1` and `data2`. I am now running a for loop and every loop merges one column in data1 with the whole columns in data2. For example

data1:

```
1 1 3 4 4 
2 5 2 4 2
2 2 8 8 0
```

data2

```
1 4 5 4 5
2 9 3 4 5
2 7 4 8 0
```

`columns 1 and 4` are duplicate in `data1` and `data2`. For the first loop, it merges

```
1 
2 
2
```

with `data2`

```
1 4 5 4 5
2 9 3 4 5
2 7 4 8 0
```

so the desired result is

```
1 4 5 4 5
2 9 3 4 5
2 7 4 8 0
```

Then it goes to the `second column`

```
 1
 5
 2
```

and it merges with `data2`

```
    1 4 5 4 5
    2 9 3 4 5
    2 7 4 8 0
```

The desired result will be

```
    1 1 4 5 4 5
    5 2 9 3 4 5
    2 2 7 4 8 0
```

My idea is to use `combine` or `merge` function, but these two functions do not achieve the desired output

```
for(i in 1:dim(data[2])){
  datam_merge<- merge(data1[i], data2)
}
```

Any suggestion is appreciated!

Comment: Are the duplicate columns are always in the same locations in both data sets (like in your example)? Then you could just simply compare them and then just `cbind`. Something like `indx <- colSums(data2 == data1) != nrow(data2) ; cbind(data2, data1[, indx])`. Also, the way you use `merges` term doesn't make sense to me- instead of merging duplicate columns you could just ignore one of them and move on, why merge them?

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```
data3 <- dplyr::left_join(data2, data1)
head(data3)
```

The `left_join()` function is determining which columns `data2` has in common with data1, and then only joining the dissimilar columns from `data1` to `data2`.

I noticed that your "desired result" is dropping column 5 from `data1`. Was this intentional, or is your desired output a new dataframe that has all of the columns from `data1` and `data2` without any duplicates?

This is another approach that may be a more generalized solution:

```
data3 <- dplyr::inner_join(data1, data2)
```

This only joins the unique columns between either of the two dataframes instead of just `data1`.

Let me know if this is what you were looking for!

**Edit:** 
Here's my example:

```
data1 <- data.frame(c(1,2,2),c(1,5,2),c(3,2,8),c(4,4,8),c(4,2,0))
names(data1) <- c("A","B","C","D","E")
data2 <- data.frame(c(1,2,2),c(4,9,7),c(5,3,4),c(4,4,8),c(5,5,0))
names(data2) <- c("A","F","G","D","H")

## columns 'A' and 'D' are in common, but we only need one of each letter ('A' through 'E').
data3 <- left_join(data2, data1)
head(data3)
  A F G D H B C E
1 1 4 5 4 5 1 3 4
2 2 9 3 4 5 5 2 2
3 2 7 4 8 0 2 8 0
```

Comment: No, `dplyr::left_join` will just join by the common column names (if not specified otherwise) which means it will join by *all* the columns and you will just get `data2` back (which is not the desired output). while `dplyr::left_join` will return and empty dataframe. Did you even check your results and compared it to the desired output?

Comment: Yes I checked my results. In this case, the output from both `left_join()` and `inner_join()` provide a new dataframe with the 8 unique columns ( removing the 2 duplicate vectors). See my edit with a reproducible example.

Comment: That's because your column names are set automatically by the values they are containing. I doubt this is true in real life, e.g. no one has `c.1..2..2.` as a column name. And btw, no need to lead dplyr in order to do a simple `merge`.

Comment: I'm just following the example I was given to work with. I've verified that it still works when the columns are named properly. See my second edit.

Comment: Are you kidding me? You are manually setting the column names in a way that when they are duplicated they will have the same name? Why `A` and `D` are the same in both data sets? Because you eyeballed the data sets and decided that they are dupes? Try with `names(data2) <- names(data1) <- paste0("V", 1:5)`

Comment: I think we are talking past each other here, no need for the attitude. Based on the information provided in the initial post, I made an honest effort to provide a solution. I made the assumption that the dataframes could be compared and joined by common colnames. If @user5802211 suggests otherwise and my answer is no longer valid, then I will gladly remove it.